# What happens when you feed DC instead of AC power into an SMPS with PFC?

Tags: power, ac, switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction

I was reading about topologies used in power factor correction like:

1. Boost FPC

[image]

2. bridgeless-boost PFC

[image]

3. Totem-pole bridgeless-boost PFC

[image]

I was wondering what would happen in each of the mentioned PFC circuits if I would feed them with high-voltage DC (200-240 V) instead of AC?

Comment: Nothing much will happen but, you cannot rely on that when choosing to do this on a real device hence, the question isn't really that useful.

Comment: Fun science fact: A *rotary converter* (obsolete but very kinetic way to convert 3-phase AC into DC) *corrects power factor for the grid it's connected to*, even if no DC load is being drawn.

Comment: @Andyaka . what do you mean nothing much will happen ? the power switches will work in passing the signal but the control logic i imagine will go nuts in trying to correct the signal . Some circuits have a zero detector (boost PFC with Critical conduction mode) .

Comment: @Andyaka . regarding the usefulness of the question . I am actually thinking about doing so to supply a couple of computers. My source of DC voltage is an Online UPS battery bank that contains 20x 12v 7Ah SLA batteries. but my concern is that the PSU will be toasted and would like your experts opinion on the subject . thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a PFC relies on shaping the switched current to follow the rectified mains voltage, since that is required in order to make correct for the power factor. For an easier explanation, considering the classic boost PFC, your 1st picture, that voltage will appear before the inductor. If its shape will be flat (e.g. DC), then the current will be shaped to have a flat envelope, which means that the PFC will become a regular DC-DC boost converter. As an example, here is how the current looks like for a normal PFC operation vs DC input (BCM PFC):

[image: BCM PFC: input current for AC and DC]

The DC current is negative due to the orientation of the supply; SPICE thing, nothing more. For the sake of comparison, here is the output voltage:

[image: BCM PFC: output voltage for AC and DC]

Comment: thank u for taking the time to simulate the circuit .could you elaborate more on this " which means that the PFC will become a regular DC-DC boost converter " . In the second curve the red is current ? . another question : if it is digitally controlled PFC , wouldn't the control go nuts trying to find the zero crossing ?

Comment: @EngSam A PFC is a boost converter: if the reference is a sine, the current will be a sine, and if the reference is DC, the current will be DC. In the first picture the currents are shown for PFC mode (blue) and for DC mode (red). The second picture shows the output voltage for PFC mode (blue) vs DC mode (red). The Y axes show the units. As for the zero crossing, that's used for the sign of the current, to know whether it's I(L) or -I(L), so having DC means the current will, again, have one polarity -- that of the DC source applied. Same thing.

Comment: ok now it is clear. So it should work normally and there is nothing to worry about ? . I was simulating a circuit -LT1249 boost PFC- and noticed that inrush current increased a lot . maybe the PFC controller was doing the inrush current limiting.

Comment: @EngSam The inrush happens anytime a power supply is switched on, but the cure for that is the soft start. Most power supplies have it nowadays, though, at a quick glance, the 1249 doesn't seem to have it. Also, don't forget that, unless you're using `uic` or `startup`, if you set the source to be (say) `165`, then it will start at that value, whereas a `SIN()` will start at zero, gradually rising. Whteher the power supply will operate at either AC or DC, that's up to the implementation, not a universal truth, but it should work. If in doubt use a bench supply, start low, with ext. protection.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, all of them are able to work just as intended with DC.

Since you will use only half of the power-bearing elements, this half may get overloaded (if it is engineered too near its limits).

The controlling circuit, on the other hand, may or may not behave.

Comment: you have in fact been very helpful in pointing out the issue of using only half the power elements. In cheap mass produced staff I am sure they try to save every penny.